# HTML Head issue using Magento2

Tags: magento2, html, header, view, head

I've an issue with **Magento 2**: please Help!

I've added some HTML code in:

`Content > Design > Configuration > Theme Edit > HTML Head`

The code doesn't work (it's ok, no worries for me, cause the site is running - except for the two lines error in the top header). I'd like to delete that HTML code, but I cannot access to

`Content > Design > Configuration > Theme Edit`

(I cannot enter the default page view - The wheel keep on rotating but nothing happens). Is there any file I can edit to delete that html code?

Comment: Have you check consol or magento log file? Is there any error?

Comment: I found this error using chrome console: Uncaught ReferenceError: _SERVER is not defined
    at eval (eval at template (template.js:43), <anonymous>:24:26)
    at template (template.js:43)
    at render (template.js:97)
    at iterate (template.js:174)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.js:150)
    at iterate (template.js:176)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.js:150)
    at Object.template (template.js:161)
    at UiClass.initConfig (class.js:89)
    at UiClass.initialize (class.js:70)

Answer (score 3):

Magento will store the content of `Content > Design > Configuration > Theme Edit > HTML Head`.  within `core_config_data` using the path `design/head/includes`.

You should be able to edit the database, or create an upgrade script to remove this value for you.  Ensure that you remove this in all the store scopes you set it up for.

MySQL would look something like: `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'design/head/includes';`

Setup script would look something like:

```
$this->_resourceConfig->saveConfig(
    'design/head/includes',
    '',
    'default',
    0
);
```

Where _resourceConfig is a `\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config`

Comment: No problem - if this answers your question, please accept it as the answer :)